# How can I reference a custom icon for a file association in Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, icons, inno-setup, launch4j

My application creates documents.  I want to have a special icon for the documents it creates, other than just the application icon.  On OS X, there is a clear way to do this via the Info.plist.  In Windows, however, I'm having trouble.  I am using Launch4J and Inno Setup.

Inno Setup [describes how to specify an icon via a file association](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc).  The example uses the application EXE that contains multiple icons, referencing them as 0, 1, 2, etc.  However, Launch4J appears to only support creating an EXE with a single icon, the application icon.  So this example won't work for me.

Here is my current `Icons` section:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
```

Here is an example file association:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".ext"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "EXT"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: associateext
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "EXT"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "EXT"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: associateext
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "EXT\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\MyProg.exe,0"; Tasks: associateext
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "EXT\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\MyProg.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: associateext
```

How can I reference a custom icon for a file association in Inno Setup?  (Or embed multiple icons in a Launch4J EXE?)

Comment: As [`the reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427(v=vs.85).aspx) mentions, the `DefaultIcon` subkey value specifies the fully qualified path for any file that contains an icon, including *.ico, *.exe, and *.dll files. Also, don't forget to set `ChangesAssociations` directive to `yes` as your linked example suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point any icon file or choose an icon from EXE/DLL file:

```
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "EXT\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; 
 ValueData: """PATH\Icon.file"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: associateext
```

In your case it could be:

```
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "EXT\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; 
 ValueData: """{app}\MyCustomIcon.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: associateext
```

Comment: I guess that's all there was to it.  Thanks.  I assumed you needed a new line in the Icon section.  I just copied the ICO resource to my application folder and referenced it as: `{app}\myprog_doc.ico`